# java.lang.NullPointerException Xamarin Facebook Android SDK on Xamarin.Forms app

Tags: android, facebook, nullpointerexception, xamarin.forms, nuget

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms project. In this app I make use of `DisplayAlert` and `DisplayActionSheet`, through a DialogService. (see below)

```
public async Task ShowMessageBox(
        string message,
        string title)
    {
        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(
            title,
            message,
            "OK");
    }
```

Then I installed (just installed... no related code implemented) the Xamarin.Facebook.Android nuget package, version `4.11.0.1` (lastest compatible version with my Xamarin.Forms `2.3.2.127`). After that, I got an exception every time I try to use my DialogService:

```
AlertController.setupView 
Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

Does anyone know what is happenning?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: No updates yet. :/